# Is there any option to connect other db in the salesforce platform?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I would like to know whether there any option to connect to the external db in the salesforce  platform.

Thanks,
Easwar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use an external database for your Salesforce data, if that's what you're asking. Salesforce data (for Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, etc.) is housed on the Salesforce platform.

However, using an [integration service](http://www.salesforce.com/platform/cloud-infrastructure/integration.jsp) (or web-services, REST API, etc.), you can connect or sync to an external database.

Here's a list of integration services:

1. [Informatica Cloud](http://www.informaticacloud.com/)
2. [Cast Iron](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/cast-iron-cloud-integration/)
3. [SnapLogic](http://www.snaplogic.com/what-we-do/integration-platform/)
4. [Boomi](http://www.boomi.com/)
5. [JitterBit](http://www.jitterbit.com/)
6. [Sesame Relational Junction](http://www.sesamesoftware.com/rj4salesforce.html)

Information on other tools, to integrate Salesforce with other databases, is available here:

1. [Salesforce Web Services API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm)
2. [Salesforce Bulk API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index.htm)
3. [Salesforce Rest API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm)

Comment: also include Pervasive Datacloud

Comment: shall we create our own java Webservice and use it in Salesforce Apex code to perform the database operations on the other DBs???
Please reply..

Comment: @Azeez It depends on your business and application design, but yes, you could do that. If you want to use an integration service, it's recommended that you use that instead of a web service to communicate between systems (SF and external DBs).