# Alternative to Apatar for scripted data migration

Tags: salesforce, data-migration

I'm looking for the fastest-to-success alternative solution for related data migration between Salesforce environments with some specific technical requirements. We were using Apatar, which worked fine in testing, but late in the game it has started throwing the dreaded socket "connection reset" errors and we have not been able to resolve it - it has some other issues that are leading me to ditch it.

I need to move a modest amount of data (about 10k rows total) between several sandboxes and ultimately to a production environment. The data is spread across eight custom objects. There is a four-level-deep master-detail relationship, which obviously must be preserved.

The target environment tables are 100% empty.

The trickiest object has a master-detail and two lookup fields.

Ideally, the data from one table near the top of the hierarchy should be filtered by a simple WHERE, and then children not under matching rows not migrated, but I'll settle for a solution that migrates all the data wholesale.

My fallback in this situation is going to be good old Data Loader, but it's not ideal because our schema is locked down and does not contain external ID fields, so scripting a solution that preserves all the M-D and lookups will take a while and be more error prone than I'd like.

It's been a long time since I've done a survey of the tools available, and don't have much time to do one now, so I'm appealing to the crowd. I need an app that will be simple (able to configure and test very quickly), repeatable, and rock-solid.

I've always pictured an SFDC data migration app that you can just check off eight checkboxes from a source environment, point it to a destination environment, and it just works, preserving all your relationships. That would be perfect. Free would be nice too. Does such a shiny thing exist?

Comment: Hey Jeremy, are you explicitly looking for a free/OpenSource tool?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it does need to be something I don't have to get four demos and three PO's to get off the ground -- like it needs to be working this weekend :) I'm currently pursuing the "patch Apatar" route and it seems to be moving in the right direction, but if you do know of any product that does what I described I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sesame Relational Junction](http://www.sesamesoftware.com/rj4salesforce.html) seems to best match what you're looking for. I haven't used it, though; so, I can't comment on its effectiveness for what you're attempting.

The other route you may want to look into is using the [Bulk API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index.htm) or using the [Data Loader CLI](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line) with [Task Scheduling](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/New-to-Cloud-Development/How-to-schedule-the-command-line-data-loader-for-inserting-the/td-p/348147).

You may find this information (below), from an answer to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616176/is-there-any-option-to-connect-other-db-in-the-salesforce-platform/9620279#9620279), helpful.

---

Here is a list of integration services (other than [Apatar](http://apatar.com/capabilities.html)):

1. [Informatica Cloud](http://www.informaticacloud.com/)
2. [Cast Iron](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/cast-iron-cloud-integration/)
3. [SnapLogic](http://www.snaplogic.com/what-we-do/integration-platform/)
4. [Boomi](http://www.boomi.com/)
5. [JitterBit](http://www.jitterbit.com/)
6. [Sesame Relational Junction](http://www.sesamesoftware.com/rj4salesforce.html)

Information on other tools, to integrate Salesforce with other databases, is available here:

1. [Salesforce Web Services API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm)
2. [Salesforce Bulk API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index.htm)

Comment: Thanks, useful as always! I'll have to take a look. In the meantime, I think we got a working solution (still testing) by upgrading a number of the libraries that Apatar's SFDC connector used. It's definitely prompted me to do a full review of what's out there these days though.

Answer (score 0):

Relational Junction has a unique feature set that supports cloning, splitting, and merging of Salesforce orgs, and will keep the relationships intact in a one-pass load. It works like this:

1. Download source org to an empty database schema (any relationship DBMS)
2. Download target org to a second empty database schema
3. Run some scripts to condition the data; this varies by object. Sesame provides guidance and sample scripts, but essentially you have to set a control field to tell Relational Junction to create or update Salesforce. This is also where you may need to replace source ID's with target ID's if some objects have been pre-populated during sandbox creation
4. Replicate the second database to the target org

Relational Junction handles the socket disconnects, timeouts, and whatever havoc happens during the unload/reload process gracefully and without creating duplicates.

This process was developed for a proof of concept at a large Silicon Valley network vendor in 2007, who became a customer. The entire down and up of 15 GB of data took 46 hours, plus about 2 days of preparation.

Comment: You should add a disclaimer that you are affiliated with the product.